# Android System has stopped error when launching share activity chooser in Android application

Tags: android

Ive implemented share button in my Android application toolbar, when button pressed the codes run

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "title");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

And the share activity opens.
But when changing activity (I have a card view with different pages) and in them opening and then closing this dialog several times the "Unfortunately Android System has stopped" error appears. My application is working ok though and I see no errors in debug console. Any solutions to the problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. Its my custom Android on Motorola Moto X bug. Android System crushes in all share choosers in other applications too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.  I was getting this error when I did the above intent call.  I figured out my issue.  I was using an Icon in my mipmap folders.  When I changed it to my drawable folder, the issue went away.  Hope this helps.